# Filtering by nested object field value in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to filter the document by nested field value. My document is like this and I want to filter it by Color parameter:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "product",
  "_id": "984984",
  "_source": {
    "id": "98418",
    "name": "Product1",
    ..
    "parameters": {
      "Color": [
        "Black",
        "Gold"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My mapping is:

```
{
  "myindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "properties": {
          ..
          "parameters": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
            "Color": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            ..
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my **filter** query is following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "parameters",
          "query": {
            "term": {    
              "parameters.Color":"Gold"
            }
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But unfortunatelly I'm getting zero documents and I do not understand why?

Thank you

## EDIT

Event this is working:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "parameters",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "parameters.Color": "Gold" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

..but this is not:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "parameters",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            { "term": { "parameters.Color": "Gold" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `term` query is looking for an exact match and the `match` query is analyzed before searching. If you are using the standard analyzer it will lowercase your terms when it analyzes them.

You could use the keyword field if you need to do an exact match.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "parameters",
          "query": {
            "term": {    
              "parameters.Color.keyword":"Gold"
            }
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```